# Button перехода на сайт

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку программа переводила на сайт компании.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте в обработчик кнопки:

```
   Uri address = Uri.parse("ссылка на сайт компании");
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: отметил, только потому что Вы - первый ответили. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В обработчик нажатия на вашу кнопку добавьте интент передающий вашу ссылку:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,    
       Uri.parse("http://www.my-company-site.ru")); 
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: тоже правильный ответ